# JS setDate() in loop

Tags: javascript, date, loops

I want to call a function for each day within next two weeks from now and pass parameters such as day and month. I use this method: `startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)` which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093322/setdateday1-returns-wrong-days) but it gets messy after first 6 steps of the loop

```
var date = new Date,
    searchDate = new Date,
    period = 14;

for(i = 1; i <= period; i++){
    searchDate.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    // someFunction(searchDate.getDate(), searchDate.getMonth());
}
```

What `console.log(i + ": " + searchDate)` returns:

```
1: Tue Aug 27 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200
2: Wed Aug 28 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200
3: Thu Aug 29 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200
4: Fri Aug 30 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200
5: Sat Aug 31 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200
6: Sun Sep 01 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200 // so far so good
7: Thu Oct 03 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0200 // and after a week it's suddenly October
8: Sun Nov 03 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0100
9: Thu Dec 05 2013 17:38:04 GMT+0100
10: Sun Jan 05 2014 17:38:04 GMT+0100
11: Thu Feb 06 2014 17:38:04 GMT+0100
12: Mon Mar 10 2014 17:38:04 GMT+0100
13: Tue Apr 08 2014 17:38:04 GMT+0200
14: Sat May 10 2014 17:38:04 GMT+0200
```

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is :

```
searchDate.setTime(date.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000 * i));
```

It adds time to the internal value (timestamp) of the date instead of adding it to the day.